# Binding element 'smth here' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Yo guys, im new to react, was trying to make a modal popup after btn click. However i got this mistake.
Binding element 'children'/active/setActive' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

```
const Modal = ({active, setActive, children}) => {
  return (
    <div className={active ? 'modal active' : 'modal'} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
      <div className={active ? 'modal__content active' : 'modal__content'} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typescript error, if you do not explicitly declare function parameter types and return types (which you should), it is set as `any` type, which seems the issue your `linter` is upset about. It does not stop your program from working, just a typescript issue.

```
setActive = (status: boolean):void => {
    //do something
}
```

this should be how you type this function.